# How to get the SIFT direction of a Harris-Laplace Keypoint？

Tags: opencv

I am reproducing a paper that first uses Gaussian filtering to process images, then uses Harris Laplace to detect feature points with rotation and scale invariance, and finally uses SURF to determine the direction of the feature point.

In my attempt, Harris-Laplace did not return keypoints with angles (or in other words, they were all 0.0). SURF was restricted in use, so I tried using SIFT instead. But the SIFT compute() method seems to be used to calculate feature descriptors, receiving keypoints and returning them along with their corresponding 128 dimensional feature descriptors. The keypoint.angle in the return value is still 0.0
Is there a function in Opencv or other algorithm libraries that calculates the SIFT direction of a point? Alternatively, can I manually calculate this value by calling a lower level function in OpenCV